# Explore Instagram graphapi

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

As for me, facebook has the most unclear documentation for developers. Let me tell about my case. I've found one interesting idea for application for instagram and I wanted to explore how instagram API works (I mean v3 for business accounts). I dived into documentation and found that I should have same ready application to pass verification and I must upload some screencast.

But I don't have any applications yet! I just have an idea and I want to play with API to understand how it worsk and satisfies my app's requirments. Is there some dev- sandbox mode for such experiments? Or maybe my approach is wrong and there is right way how to play with instagram graph api?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to test and experiment.

But for that you will at-least need to setup an app and put that to development mode. App review is necessary before going live.